# How can one use TogetherJS as a chat app?

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, chat, session-storage

I want to add simple chat and collaboration to my (Rails) website. [TogetherJS](https://togetherjs.com/) is Mozilla's open-source JavaScript library for real-time collaboration. It can easily be dropped into a website and just works.

However, to collaborate with someone, you need to send them a link. Users on a website don't know who is on, so they can't send someone else a link. How can one get around this?

(One idea is to create a session on TogetherJS and then show that link to everyone on the site so they can join in if they want.)

Answer (score 3):

It's built in. Start a session, share the collaboration link, done. The together.js dock has a chat button. If you want everyone to be able to join, make that link something that can be template-dropped-in into your html file, or make sure there is an always-available-link by starting a session, saving its URL, and then just hardcoding that link on your site for people to click.

Comment: Can one link work permanently? I wasn't sure how that worked.

Comment: yeah, the togetherjs library simply uses the fragment identifier as a session identifier, so if everyone loads the same link, which will have the same fragment id, they're all dropped into the same session.

Comment: Cool. I guess I'll just disable page following and have a chat with optional collaboration features.

Comment: just as a small warning: all your users in the same session is going to be chaos =D (we tried it with about 20 users, it gets quite... unwieldy. But, hilariously so)

Comment: TogetherJS has some options which help setup what I wanted. (See my answer's links.)

Answer (score 3):

TogetherJS has an option to create rooms, which looks like it allows the chat I'm looking for. The [documentation](https://togetherjs.com/docs/#configuring-togetherjs) doesn't go into so much detail, but the [togetherjs.js source code](https://github.com/mozilla/togetherjs/blob/e83e9199611cb48a77b0afc0301c7d7244c96e63/togetherjs/togetherjs.js) has helpful comments:

```
// Used to auto-start TogetherJS with a {prefix: pageName, max: participants}   
// Also with findRoom: "roomName" it will connect to the given room name   
findRoom: null,
```

They also have [example apps](https://github.com/mozilla/togetherjs/blob/77dc7cbcfe3b87d0c9d9a8f8cb47c96164d7c467/site/examples/madlibs/index.html) that demonstrate its use:

```
<script>
      TogetherJSConfig_findRoom = {prefix: "togetherjsmadlibs", max: 5};
      TogetherJSConfig_autoStart = true;
      TogetherJSConfig_suppressJoinConfirmation = true;
      TogetherJSConfig_storagePrefix = "tjs_madlibs";
</script>
```